# Как излучить событие из компонента диалог?

Tags: javascript, angular2

Помогите пожалуйста включить видимость компонента `spinner` из компонента `dialog`

У меня есть родительский компонент. В его шаблоне есть тег компонента `spinner`. Я хотел бы менять видимость этого тега по сигналу из других компонентов, в частности из компонента `dialog`

Итак, после клика по какой-нибудь кнопке у меня открывается модальное окно, сделанное при помощи стандартного компонента `dialog`. Далее я излучаю (`emit`) событие из компонента `dialog` в родительский. И в родительском компоненте обрабатываю это событие

Проблема в том, что, вероятно, компонент `dialog` не является дочерним для моего родительского компонента. Поэтому излучение события не работает. Следовательно спиннер не показывается

Пожалуйста на словах объясните что мне делать

Comment: А что за компонент `dialog`? Ваш самописный или из какой-то библиотеки?

Comment: из ng-material 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с использованием Font Awesome.

В `app.component.ts` добавляем `<app-spinner></app-spinner>`
а в нужном месте приложения, в конструкторе `private spinnerService: SpinnerService`, и в методе, вызываем вначале `this.spinnerService.show();`, а после `this.spinnerService.hidde()`;

**spinner.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

export interface SpinnerState {
  show: boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService implements OnInit  {
  private spinnerSubject = new Subject<SpinnerState>();
  // tslint:disable-next-line:member-ordering
  spinnerState = this.spinnerSubject.asObservable();

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.spinnerSubject.next(<SpinnerState>{ show: false });
  }

  show() {
    this.spinnerSubject.next(<SpinnerState>{ show: true });
  }

  hide() {
    this.spinnerSubject.next(<SpinnerState>{ show: false });
  }
}
```

**spinner.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { SpinnerState, SpinnerService } from '../_services/spinner.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-spinner',
  template: '<div class="spinner" [class.spinner-hidden]="!visible"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only"> Loading...</span></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.css']
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  visible = false;

  private spinnerStateChanged: Subscription;

  constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.visible);
    this.spinnerStateChanged = this.spinnerService.spinnerState
      .subscribe((state: SpinnerState) => {
        this.visible = state.show;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.spinnerStateChanged.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**spinner.component.css**

```
.spinner{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.spinner-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```